# Angular UNIVERSAL prerender error Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver [object Object]

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

I'm having problems rendering my site, in the past it worked fine but i had to reinstall node and angular and it stops working I'm on a m1 macbook pro.

Angular: 14.2.7

Node: v16.18.0

✖ Prerendering routes to /Users/anya/Documents/dev/practice-landing/dist/siem-new-landing/browser failed.
Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver [object Object]

Comment: The same happens to me. It seems to be related to the Node version. With v16.16.0 it works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing similair issue with my Azure Pipelines when the NodeJS version wasn't defined, then it took the latest LTS `v16.18.0`. I think there is a issue with NodeJS `v16.18.0` and Angular compatibility. As a temporary workaround, I did downgrade the NodeJS to `v16.17.1` which fixed the issue as of now. Will update this reply if I find a permanent solution.

**UPDATE**:
After upgrading to Angular `v15`, the compatibility issue with NodeJS `v16.18.0` has been fixed and Azure Pipelines works with LTS too.

Answer (score 1):

same here: Angular 14.1.3 & azure pipelines. Specifying FROM Node 16.17 in dockerfile solved it for now. thanks!

Comment: The answer does not add any additional information to the highest-voted answer from simfyz. Please upvote the other answer instead in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Someone made a bug & pr if you guys want to stay up to date: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47872