# Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver [object Object] Angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

hi after running the command ng add @nguniversal/express-engine to enable ssr my page is still not found by google so i assume you need to run the command npm run prerender too
however this command is failing with  `Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver [object Object]`
does anyone know how to solve this

`prerendering routes too the folder dist/laschan/browser fails`
how do i change this path?

```
> laschan@0.0.0 prerender
> ng run laschan:prerender

Node.js version v19.0.0 detected.
Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files           | Names         |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
main.23c37bdc92845569.js      | main          | 313.07 kB |                79.81 kB
styles.8dbebd639b78f3dc.css   | styles        | 274.23 kB |                27.60 kB
polyfills.ee03e0177549f1dd.js | polyfills     |  33.07 kB |                10.65 kB
runtime.cb900ddd8f87bc86.js   | runtime       |   1.04 kB |               586 bytes

                              | Initial Total | 621.41 kB |               118.64 kB

Build at: 2022-10-28T10:53:55.924Z - Hash: a6798a3bd0415af2 - Time: 14788ms

Warning: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 500.00 kB was not met by 121.41 kB with a total of 621.41 kB.


✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         | Raw Size
main.js             | main          |  3.66 MB | 

                    | Initial Total |  3.66 MB

Build at: 2022-10-28T10:54:06.975Z - Hash: 6e80476241acb45a - Time: 25857ms
✖ Prerendering routes to /root/landing.appologi.es/dist/laschan/browser failed.
Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
```

Comment: You should probably include the whole stacktrace of the error occuring in order to receive helpful feedback.

Comment: how do i print the stack trace?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062266/angular-universal-prerender-error-method-promise-prototype-then-called-on-incomp

Comment: same error with node version 16.18.0 and 19.0.0 node version 16.17.0 not found

Comment: `prerender` is not what you need, that command generates html pages on your development machine, and so is only for static prerendering

Comment: What backend stack are you using? ASP.NET Core? MVC framework developers usually provide packages to help you with this